# Solve pagination issues

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application where i added pagination functionality using react js. Also i have there search functionality which also works. The issue appears when i go to second page, and i delete all items from that page. In that moment where i delete the last item from page, the page should go on the previous page, but it still on the second without any item, but this should be automatically. The same issue is with search. When i am on the second page and i search the text `first`, the result is on first page, but i am on the second, or in this case automatically the pages should change, and i should see the result.

How to solve these 2 issues?

Comment: Well first of all why `total={15}` is hadcoded value instead of `mydata.length`?

Comment: @lazy.lizard, it is my fault, forgot to change. But the issue also exists.

Comment: @lazy.lizard, did you find a solution?

Comment: @Utsav Patel, do you have an idea for this?

Comment: Your search changes `mydata`, which doesn't allow deleting from the search bar. Use `displayedData` of some kind, as the data should remain static

Comment: @GalAbra, i didn't understand actually, what is displayedData?, could you show me, please.

Comment: Your data shouldn't be affected by your search - hence it should be static

Comment: @Dennis Vash, could you take a look, please?

Answer (score 1):

You need to make two changes to your code:

1. In your `search` function, you should filter `data` rather than `mydata`, otherwise your search won't reset upon every update:

```js
const search = e => {
  const v = e.target.value;
  const result = data.filter(i =>
  //             ^ This was `mydata`
    i.title.toLowerCase().includes(v.toLowerCase())
  );
  setMyData(result);
};
```

2. The `total` prop of `Pagination` should be defined dynamically, so the amount of pages matches the amount of items:

```
<Pagination
  defaultCurrent={1}
  defaultPageSize={9}
  onChange={handleChange}
  total={mydata.length}
  //     ^ This was hard-coded
/>
```