# Issue with page number

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an application where I use a click counter.

```
const App = () => {
  const [nr, setNr] = useState(1);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{nr}</p>
      <Pagination defaultCurrent={nr} total={50} />
      <button onClick={() => setNr(nr + 1)}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Depending on the value the `defaultCurrent` should change in my Pagination component, but it is not working even the values are changing. Why the pages don't change when I click on the counter?

Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-ant-design-demo-ni423?file=/Test.js:183-386

Comment: The sandbox has an error. You're not rendering the `button` and `p`

Comment: `<Pagination current={nr} total={50} />`

Comment: @palaѕн, but why after i click on the button click (for example till 3), and after that if i click on the button 1 , the active also still and 3?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`defaultCurrent` is only **initialized on mount**, therefore you should use the `current` property.

See example:

[image: Edit Basic - Ant Design Demo]

- [Pagination docs](https://ant.design/components/pagination/).

Comment: but why after i click on the button `click` (for example till 3), and after that if i click on the button `1` , the active also still and  `3`?

Comment: I added a codesandbox to the answer, check it, you should use `onChange` for it to work

Comment: Ok, i will accept your ansewr, but could you take a look on my another question, please?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61265277/solve-pagination-issues/61266352#61266352

Answer (score 1):

You should use `current` prop:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [nr, setNr] = useState(1);
  return (
    <div>
      <p>{nr}</p>
      <Pagination current={nr} total={50} />
      <button onClick={() => setNr(nr + 1)}>click</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: but why after i click on the button click (for example till 3), and after that if i click on the button 1 , the active also still and 3?